# Which Python packages offer a stand-alone event system?

Tags: python, events, event-handling, dispatcher

I am aware of [pydispatcher](http://pydispatcher.sourceforge.net/), but there must be other event-related packages around for Python.

Which libraries are available?

I'm not interested in event managers that are part of large frameworks, I'd rather use a small bare-bones solution that I can easily extend.

Answer (score 299, accepted):

## PyPI packages

As of October 2022, these are the event-related packages available on PyPI,
ordered by most recent release date.

- [PyDispatcher](https://pypi.org/project/PyDispatcher/) `2.0.6`: Aug 2022
- [blinker](https://pypi.org/project/blinker/) `1.5`: Jun 2022
- [pymitter](https://pypi.org/project/pymitter/) `0.4.0`: June 2022
- [python-dispatch](https://pypi.org/project/python-dispatch/) `0.2.0`: Apr 2022
- [pluggy](https://pypi.org/project/pluggy/) `1.0.0`: August 2021
- [Events](https://pypi.org/project/Events/) `0.4`: October 2020
- [zope.event](https://pypi.org/project/zope.event/) `4.5.0`: Sept 2020
- [RxPy3](https://pypi.org/project/RxPy3/) `1.0.1`: June 2020
- [Louie](https://pypi.org/project/Louie/) `2.0`: Sept 2019
- [PyPubSub](https://pypi.org/project/PyPubSub/) `4.0.3`: Jan 2019
- [pyeventdispatcher](https://pypi.org/project/pyeventdispatcher/) `0.2.3a0`: 2018
- [buslane](https://pypi.org/project/buslane/) `0.0.5`: 2018
- [PyPyDispatcher](https://pypi.org/project/PyPyDispatcher/) `2.1.2`: 2017
- [axel](https://pypi.org/project/axel/) `0.0.7`: 2016
- [dispatcher](https://pypi.org/project/dispatcher/) `1.0`: 2012
- [py-notify](https://pypi.org/project/py-notify/) `0.3.1`: 2008

## There's more

That's a lot of libraries to choose from, using very different terminology (events, signals, handlers, method dispatch, hooks, ...).

I'm trying to keep an overview of the above packages, plus the techniques mentioned in the answers here.

First, some terminology...

### Observer pattern

The most basic style of event system is the 'bag of handler methods', which is a
simple implementation of the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Basically, the handler methods (callables) are stored in an array and are each called when the event 'fires'.

### Publish-Subscribe

The disadvantage of Observer event systems is that you can only register the handlers on the actual Event
object (or handlers list).  So at registration time the event already needs to exist.

That's why the second style of event systems exists: the
[publish-subscribe pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern).
Here, the handlers don't register on an event object (or handler list), but on a central dispatcher.
Also the notifiers only talk to the dispatcher.  What to listen for, or what to publish is
determined by 'signal', which is nothing more than a name (string).

### Mediator pattern

Might be of interest as well: the [Mediator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern).

### Hooks

A 'hook' system is usally used in the context of application plugins.  The
application contains fixed integration points (hooks), and each plugin may
connect to that hook and perform certain actions.

### Other 'events'

Note: [threading.Event](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/threading.html#event-objects) is not an 'event system'
in the above sense.  It's a thread synchronization system where one thread waits until another thread 'signals' the Event object.

Network messaging libraries often use the term 'events' too; sometimes these are similar in concept; sometimes not.
They can of course traverse thread-, process- and computer boundaries. See e.g.
[pyzmq](https://pypi.org/project/pyzmq/), [pymq](https://github.com/thrau/pymq),
[Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/), [Tornado](https://www.tornadoweb.org/),  [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/), [eventlet](http://eventlet.net/).

### Weak references

In Python, holding a reference to a method or object ensures that it won't get deleted
by the garbage collector.  This can be desirable, but it can also lead to memory leaks:
the linked handlers are never
cleaned up.

Some event systems use weak references instead of regular ones to solve this.

## Some words about the various libraries

Observer-style event systems:

- [zope.event](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zope.event) shows the bare bones of how this works (see [Lennart's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1092617/1075152)). Note: this example does not even support handler arguments.
- [LongPoke's 'callable list'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2022629/1075152) implementation shows that such an event system can be implemented very minimalistically by subclassing `list`.
- Felk's variation [EventHook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092531/event-system-in-python/35957226#35957226) also ensures the signatures of callees and callers.
- [spassig's EventHook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1094423/1075152) (Michael Foord's Event Pattern) is a straightforward implementation.
- [Josip's Valued Lessons Event class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1096614/1075152) is basically the same, but uses a `set` instead of a `list` to store the bag, and implements `__call__` which are both reasonable additions.
- [PyNotify](https://pypi.org/project/py-notify/) is similar in concept and also provides additional concepts of variables and conditions ('variable changed event').  Homepage is not functional.
- [axel](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/axel) is basically a bag-of-handlers with more features related to threading, error handling, ...
- [python-dispatch](https://pypi.org/project/python-dispatch/) requires the even source classes to derive from `pydispatch.Dispatcher`.
- [buslane](https://pypi.org/project/buslane/) is class-based, supports single- or multiple handlers and facilitates extensive type hints.
- Pithikos' [Observer/Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092531/event-system-in-python/28479007#28479007) is a lightweight design.

Publish-subscribe libraries:

- [blinker](https://pypi.org/project/blinker/) has some nifty features such as automatic disconnection and filtering based on sender.
- [PyPubSub](http://pypubsub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is a stable package, and promises "advanced features that facilitate debugging and maintaining topics and messages".
- [pymitter](https://github.com/riga/pymitter) is a Python port of Node.js EventEmitter2 and offers namespaces, wildcards and TTL.
- [PyDispatcher](http://pydispatcher.sourceforge.net/) seems to emphasize flexibility with regards to many-to-many publication etc.  Supports weak references.
- [louie](https://github.com/11craft/louie) is a reworked PyDispatcher and should work "in a wide variety of contexts".
- [pypydispatcher](https://github.com/scrapy/pypydispatcher) is based on (you guessed it...) PyDispatcher and also works in PyPy.
- [django.dispatch](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/dispatch) is a rewritten PyDispatcher "with a more limited interface, but higher performance".
- [pyeventdispatcher](https://github.com/whisller/pyeventdispatcher) is based on PHP's Symfony framework's event-dispatcher.
- [dispatcher](https://pypi.org/project/dispatcher/) was extracted from django.dispatch but is getting fairly old.
- Cristian Garcia's [EventManger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092531/event-system-in-python/20807692#20807692) is a really short implementation.

Others:

- [pluggy](https://pypi.org/project/pluggy/) contains a hook system which is used by `pytest` plugins.
- [RxPy3](https://pypi.org/project/RxPy3/) implements the Observable pattern and allows merging events, retry etc.
- Qt's Signals and Slots are available from [PyQt](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html)
  or [PySide2](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Python_Signals_and_Slots). They work as callback when used in the same thread,
  or as events (using an event loop) between two different threads.  Signals and Slots have the limitation that they
  only work in objects of classes that derive from `QObject`.

Comment: Since I'm working with Django, I tried `django.dispatch`, and it works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 118):

I've been doing it this way:

```
class Event(list):
    """Event subscription.

    A list of callable objects. Calling an instance of this will cause a
    call to each item in the list in ascending order by index.

    Example Usage:
    >>> def f(x):
    ...     print 'f(%s)' % x
    >>> def g(x):
    ...     print 'g(%s)' % x
    >>> e = Event()
    >>> e()
    >>> e.append(f)
    >>> e(123)
    f(123)
    >>> e.remove(f)
    >>> e()
    >>> e += (f, g)
    >>> e(10)
    f(10)
    g(10)
    >>> del e[0]
    >>> e(2)
    g(2)

    """
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for f in self:
            f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Event(%s)" % list.__repr__(self)
```

However, like with everything else I've seen, there is no auto generated pydoc for this, and no signatures, which really sucks.

Comment: I find this style rather intriguing. It's sweetly bare-bones. I like the fact that it allows one to manipulate events and their subscribers as autonomous operations. I'll see how it fares in a real project.

Comment: big favor, could someone explain this like i was 10? Does this class get inherited by the main class? I don't see a __init__ so super() wouldn't be used. It's not clicking for me for some reason.

Comment: @omgimdrunk A simple event handler would fire off one or more callable functions whenever an event fired. A class to "manage" this for you would require the following methods at a minimum - add & fire. Within that class you would need to maintain a list of handlers to be executed. Let's put that in the instance variable `_bag_of_handlers` which is a list. The class's add method would simply be `self._bag_of_handlers.append(some_callable)`. The class's fire method would loop thru` _bag_of_handlers` passing the provided args and kwargs to the handlers and execute each in sequence.

Comment: @omgimdrunk This code sits on top of the list object. Instead of the `add` method you just use append like you would for any list. Instead of the `fire` method this Event class uses the` __call__` magic method.

Comment: This technique prevents instances to be GC'ed if a method of theirs is used as a callback and not explicitly removed from the event's list

Answer (score 77):

We use an EventHook as suggested from Michael Foord in his [Event Pattern](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/weblog/arch_d7_2007_02_03.shtml#e616):

Just add EventHooks to your classes with:

```
class MyBroadcaster()
    def __init__():
        self.onChange = EventHook()

theBroadcaster = MyBroadcaster()

# add a listener to the event
theBroadcaster.onChange += myFunction

# remove listener from the event
theBroadcaster.onChange -= myFunction

# fire event
theBroadcaster.onChange.fire()
```

We add the functionality to remove all listener from an object to Michaels class and ended up with this:

```
class EventHook(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.__handlers = []

    def __iadd__(self, handler):
        self.__handlers.append(handler)
        return self

    def __isub__(self, handler):
        self.__handlers.remove(handler)
        return self

    def fire(self, *args, **keywargs):
        for handler in self.__handlers:
            handler(*args, **keywargs)

    def clearObjectHandlers(self, inObject):
        for theHandler in self.__handlers:
            if theHandler.im_self == inObject:
                self -= theHandler
```

Comment: A drawback of using this is that you need to first add an event before you register as a subscriber. If only the publishers add their events (not a must, just a good practice), then you must initialize the publishers before the subscribers which is a pain in large projects

Comment: the last method is bugged because self.__handlers is modified during the iterations. Fix: `        self.__handlers = [h for h in self.__handlers if h.im_self != obj]`

Comment: @Simon is right, but introduces a bug because we can have unbound functions in self.__handlers. Fix: `self.__handlers = [h for h in self._handlers if getattr(h, 'im_self', False) != obj]`

Answer (score 23):

I use [zope.event](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zope.event). It's the most bare bones you can imagine. :-)
In fact, here is the complete source code:

```
subscribers = []

def notify(event):
    for subscriber in subscribers:
        subscriber(event)
```

Note that you can't send messages between processes, for example. It's not a messaging system, just an event system, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: I'd still like to be able to send messages. I'd be using the event system in application built on Tkinter. I'm not using it's event system because it doesn't support messages.

Comment: You can send whatever you want with zope.event. But my point is that it's not a proper messaging system, as you can't send events/messages to other processes or other computers. You should probably be a but more specific with your requirements.

Answer (score 18):

I found this small script on [Valued Lessons](http://www.valuedlessons.com/2008/04/events-in-python.html). It seems to have just the right simplicity/power ratio I'm after. Peter Thatcher is the author of following code (no licensing is mentioned).

```
class Event:
    def __init__(self):
        self.handlers = set()

    def handle(self, handler):
        self.handlers.add(handler)
        return self

    def unhandle(self, handler):
        try:
            self.handlers.remove(handler)
        except:
            raise ValueError("Handler is not handling this event, so cannot unhandle it.")
        return self

    def fire(self, *args, **kargs):
        for handler in self.handlers:
            handler(*args, **kargs)

    def getHandlerCount(self):
        return len(self.handlers)

    __iadd__ = handle
    __isub__ = unhandle
    __call__ = fire
    __len__  = getHandlerCount

class MockFileWatcher:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fileChanged = Event()

    def watchFiles(self):
        source_path = "foo"
        self.fileChanged(source_path)

def log_file_change(source_path):
    print "%r changed." % (source_path,)

def log_file_change2(source_path):
    print "%r changed!" % (source_path,)

watcher              = MockFileWatcher()
watcher.fileChanged += log_file_change2
watcher.fileChanged += log_file_change
watcher.fileChanged -= log_file_change2
watcher.watchFiles()
```

Comment: Using a set() instead of a list is nice to avoid handlers being registered twice.  One consequence is that the handlers are not being called in the order they were registered.  Not necessarily a bad thing though...

Comment: @florisla could swap out for OrderedSet, if one so desired.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a minimal design that should work fine. What you have to do is to simply inherit `Observer` in a class and afterwards use `observe(event_name, callback_fn)` to listen for a specific event. Whenever that specific event is fired anywhere in the code (ie. `Event('USB connected')`), the corresponding callback will fire.

```
class Observer():
    _observers = []
    def __init__(self):
        self._observers.append(self)
        self._observed_events = []
    def observe(self, event_name, callback_fn):
        self._observed_events.append({'event_name' : event_name, 'callback_fn' : callback_fn})


class Event():
    def __init__(self, event_name, *callback_args):
        for observer in Observer._observers:
            for observable in observer._observed_events:
                if observable['event_name'] == event_name:
                    observable['callback_fn'](*callback_args)
```

Example:

```
class Room(Observer):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Room is ready.")
        Observer.__init__(self) # DON'T FORGET THIS
    def someone_arrived(self, who):
        print(who + " has arrived!")

# Observe for specific event
room = Room()
room.observe('someone arrived',  room.someone_arrived)

# Fire some events
Event('someone left',    'John')
Event('someone arrived', 'Lenard') # will output "Lenard has arrived!"
Event('someone Farted',  'Lenard')
```

Comment: I like your design, it's minimalistic and easy to understand. and it'd be lightweight by not having to import some modules.

Answer (score 10):

I created an `EventManager` class (code at the end). The syntax is the following:

```
#Create an event with no listeners assigned to it
EventManager.addEvent( eventName = [] )

#Create an event with listeners assigned to it
EventManager.addEvent( eventName = [fun1, fun2,...] )

#Create any number event with listeners assigned to them
EventManager.addEvent( eventName1 = [e1fun1, e1fun2,...], eventName2 = [e2fun1, e2fun2,...], ... )

#Add or remove listener to an existing event
EventManager.eventName += extra_fun
EventManager.eventName -= removed_fun

#Delete an event
del EventManager.eventName

#Fire the event
EventManager.eventName()
```

Here is an Example:

```
def hello(name):
    print "Hello {}".format(name)
    
def greetings(name):
    print "Greetings {}".format(name)

EventManager.addEvent( salute = [greetings] )
EventManager.salute += hello

print "\nInitial salute"
EventManager.salute('Oscar')

print "\nNow remove greetings"
EventManager.salute -= greetings
EventManager.salute('Oscar')
```

Output:

> Initial salute 
> Greetings Oscar 
> Hello Oscar
>
> Now remove greetings 
> Hello Oscar

EventManger Code:

```
class EventManager:
    
    class Event:
        def __init__(self,functions):
            if type(functions) is not list:
                raise ValueError("functions parameter has to be a list")
            self.functions = functions
            
        def __iadd__(self,func):
            self.functions.append(func)
            return self
            
        def __isub__(self,func):
            self.functions.remove(func)
            return self
            
        def __call__(self,*args,**kvargs):
            for func in self.functions : func(*args,**kvargs)
            
    @classmethod
    def addEvent(cls,**kvargs):
        """
        addEvent( event1 = [f1,f2,...], event2 = [g1,g2,...], ... )
        creates events using **kvargs to create any number of events. Each event recieves a list of functions,
        where every function in the list recieves the same parameters.
        
        Example:
        
        def hello(): print "Hello ",
        def world(): print "World"
        
        EventManager.addEvent( salute = [hello] )
        EventManager.salute += world
        
        EventManager.salute()
        
        Output:
        Hello World
        """
        for key in kvargs.keys():
            if type(kvargs[key]) is not list:
                raise ValueError("value has to be a list")
            else:
                kvargs[key] = cls.Event(kvargs[key])
        
        cls.__dict__.update(kvargs)
```

Answer (score 10):

You may have a look at [pymitter](https://github.com/riga/pymitter) ([pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymitter)). Its a small single-file (~250 loc) approach
"providing namespaces, wildcards and TTL".

Here's a basic example:

```
from pymitter import EventEmitter

ee = EventEmitter()

# decorator usage
@ee.on("myevent")
def handler1(arg):
   print "handler1 called with", arg

# callback usage
def handler2(arg):
    print "handler2 called with", arg
ee.on("myotherevent", handler2)

# emit
ee.emit("myevent", "foo")
# -> "handler1 called with foo"

ee.emit("myotherevent", "bar")
# -> "handler2 called with bar"
```

Answer (score 9):

I made a variation of Longpoke's minimalistic approach that also ensures the signatures for both callees and callers:

```
class EventHook(object):
    '''
    A simple implementation of the Observer-Pattern.
    The user can specify an event signature upon inizializazion,
    defined by kwargs in the form of argumentname=class (e.g. id=int).
    The arguments' types are not checked in this implementation though.
    Callables with a fitting signature can be added with += or removed with -=.
    All listeners can be notified by calling the EventHook class with fitting
    arguments.

    >>> event = EventHook(id=int, data=dict)
    >>> event += lambda id, data: print("%d %s" % (id, data))
    >>> event(id=5, data={"foo": "bar"})
    5 {'foo': 'bar'}

    >>> event = EventHook(id=int)
    >>> event += lambda wrong_name: None
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        ...
    ValueError: Listener must have these arguments: (id=int)

    >>> event = EventHook(id=int)
    >>> event += lambda id: None
    >>> event(wrong_name=0)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        ...
    ValueError: This EventHook must be called with these arguments: (id=int)
    '''
    def __init__(self, **signature):
        self._signature = signature
        self._argnames = set(signature.keys())
        self._handlers = []

    def _kwargs_str(self):
        return ", ".join(k+"="+v.__name__ for k, v in self._signature.items())

    def __iadd__(self, handler):
        params = inspect.signature(handler).parameters
        valid = True
        argnames = set(n for n in params.keys())
        if argnames != self._argnames:
            valid = False
        for p in params.values():
            if p.kind == p.VAR_KEYWORD:
                valid = True
                break
            if p.kind not in (p.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD, p.KEYWORD_ONLY):
                valid = False
                break
        if not valid:
            raise ValueError("Listener must have these arguments: (%s)"
                             % self._kwargs_str())
        self._handlers.append(handler)
        return self

    def __isub__(self, handler):
        self._handlers.remove(handler)
        return self

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if args or set(kwargs.keys()) != self._argnames:
            raise ValueError("This EventHook must be called with these " +
                             "keyword arguments: (%s)" % self._kwargs_str())
        for handler in self._handlers[:]:
            handler(**kwargs)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "EventHook(%s)" % self._kwargs_str()
```

Comment: I do love this solution, however watch out that _kwargs_str(...) may crash if there is no v.__name__ attribute (happened to me with typing.Dict).

A simple rewrite of thus function may be like:

'''
    def _kwargs_str(self):
        return ", ".join(k + "=" +
                         (v.__name__ if hasattr(v, "__name__") else v.name if hasattr(v, "name") else str(v))
                         for k, v in self._signature.items())
'''

Answer (score 3):

If I do code in pyQt I use QT sockets/signals paradigm, same is for django

If I'm doing async I/O I use native select module

If I'm usign a SAX python parser I'm using event API provided by SAX. So it looks like I'm victim of underlying API :-)

Maybe you should ask yourself what do you expect from event framework/module. My personal preference is to use Socket/Signal paradigm from QT. more info about that can be found [here](http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Python_introduction_to_signals_and_slots)

Answer (score 2):

Here's another [module](https://pypi.org/project/py-notify/) for consideration. It seems a viable choice for more demanding applications.

> Py-notify is a Python package
>   providing tools for implementing
>   Observer programming pattern. These
>   tools include signals, conditions and
>   variables.
>
> Signals are lists of handlers that are
>   called when signal is emitted.
>   Conditions are basically boolean
>   variables coupled with a signal that
>   is emitted when condition state
>   changes. They can be combined using
>   standard logical operators (not, and,
>   etc.) into compound conditions.
>   Variables, unlike conditions, can hold
>   any Python object, not just booleans,
>   but they cannot be combined.

Comment: The home page is out of commission for this one, perhaps not being supported any longer?

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to do more complicated things like merging events or retry you can use the Observable pattern and a mature library that implements that. https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxPY . Observables are very common in Javascript and Java and very convenient to use for some async tasks.

```
from rx import Observable, Observer


def push_five_strings(observer):
        observer.on_next("Alpha")
        observer.on_next("Beta")
        observer.on_next("Gamma")
        observer.on_next("Delta")
        observer.on_next("Epsilon")
        observer.on_completed()


class PrintObserver(Observer):

    def on_next(self, value):
        print("Received {0}".format(value))

    def on_completed(self):
        print("Done!")

    def on_error(self, error):
        print("Error Occurred: {0}".format(error))

source = Observable.create(push_five_strings)

source.subscribe(PrintObserver())
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Received Alpha
Received Beta
Received Gamma
Received Delta
Received Epsilon
Done!
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need an eventbus that works across process or network boundaries you can try [PyMQ](https://github.com/thrau/pymq). It currently supports pub/sub, message queues and synchronous RPC. The default version works on top of a Redis backend, so you need a running Redis server. There is also an in-memory backend for testing. You can also write your own backend.

```py
import pymq

# common code
class MyEvent:
    pass

# subscribe code
@pymq.subscriber
def on_event(event: MyEvent):
    print('event received')

# publisher code
pymq.publish(MyEvent())

# you can also customize channels
pymq.subscribe(on_event, channel='my_channel')
pymq.publish(MyEvent(), channel='my_channel')
```

To initialize the system:

```py
from pymq.provider.redis import RedisConfig

# starts a new thread with a Redis event loop
pymq.init(RedisConfig())

# main application control loop

pymq.shutdown()
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of this library

Answer (score 2):

Another handy package is [events](https://pypi.org/project/Events/). It encapsulates the core to event subscription and event firing and feels like a "natural" part of the language. It seems similar to the C# language, which provides a handy way to declare, subscribe to and fire events. Technically, an event is a "slot" where callback functions (event handlers) can be attached to - a process referred to as subscribing to an event.

```py
# Define a callback function
def something_changed(reason):
    print "something changed because %s" % reason

# Use events module to create an event and register one or more callback functions
from events import Events
events = Events()
events.on_change += something_changed
```

When the event is fired, all attached event handlers are invoked in sequence. To fire the event, perform a call on the slot:

```py
events.on_change('it had to happen')
```

This will output:

```
'something changed because it had to happen'
```

More documentation can be found in the [github repo](https://github.com/pyeve/events) or the [documentation](https://events.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Answer (score 1):

You can try [`buslane`](https://github.com/konradhalas/buslane) module.

This library makes implementation of message-based system easier. It supports commands (single handler) and events (0 or multiple handlers) approach. Buslane uses Python type annotations to properly register handler.

Simple example:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

from buslane.commands import Command, CommandHandler, CommandBus


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class RegisterUserCommand(Command):
    email: str
    password: str


class RegisterUserCommandHandler(CommandHandler[RegisterUserCommand]):

    def handle(self, command: RegisterUserCommand) -> None:
        assert command == RegisterUserCommand(
            email='john@lennon.com',
            password='secret',
        )


command_bus = CommandBus()
command_bus.register(handler=RegisterUserCommandHandler())
command_bus.execute(command=RegisterUserCommand(
    email='john@lennon.com',
    password='secret',
))
```

To install buslane, simply use pip:

```
$ pip install buslane
```

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago I've wrote library that might be useful for you. 
It allows you to have local and global listeners, multiple different ways of registering them, execution priority and so on.

```
from pyeventdispatcher import register

register("foo.bar", lambda event: print("second"))
register("foo.bar", lambda event: print("first "), -100)

dispatch(Event("foo.bar", {"id": 1}))
# first second
```

Have a look [pyeventdispatcher](https://github.com/whisller/pyeventdispatcher)