# Initializing at a specific moment

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I've been playing around in Python and using `__init__` etc.

Now I was wondering if you could do something else that would execute a piece of code (basically jump to that part of code) when triggered.

Easiest way to make it clear I think is like when a player in a game dies, he should just die and not get any more chances of having a turn or whatever.

I know this can be done in other ways, but the point is this may not always be nice.

I was thinking of something like (note: this is completely made up):

```
__as-soon-as__ PlayerHealth < 1: ## End what you are doing and do this when PlayerHealth is less than 1##
    print('Game Over')
```

So the real question is: Does anything like this exist?

Comment: You can `break` from `for` or `while` loops, `return` early from functions, `raise` and catch an error - there are plenty of options.

Comment: This would totally depend on what `PlayerHealth` is and how it is updated. Generally, implement this logic with a simple `if` statement in the code where `PlayerHealth` is changed.

Comment: You could implement this by making PlayerHealth a property of a Player object, then registering callbacks on the setter, one of which would be a method that checks if the player is dead and prints "Game Over" if so.  However, generally, something like this would be handled outside the object itself (division of responsibility; the game knows about the player, the player doesn't know about the game) in a game loop.  This may really be an XY problem, in that case.  Can you show more code, or describe more of the structure of your program?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is using events in python.

There are several event frameworks that you could use [PyDispatcher](https://launchpad.net/pydispatcher) or similar frameworks like the ones mentioned in florisla's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16192256/3608631)

But to keep this lightweight a simpler choice would be to use the [event/signal dispatcher](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578307-python-a-eventsignal-dispatcher/) recipe  from ActiveState. This will enable you to send simple events when the conditions you need are met.