# Connections between different classes

Tags: python

please consider the following code:

```
class A:
    a = "a"

    def print_a(self):
        print("A says:", self.a)

    def print_warning_a(self):
        print("A says:", "Warning! B wrote something!")


class B:
    b = "b"

    def print_a(self):
        print("B says:", self.b)

    def print_warning_b(self):
        print("B says:", "Warning! A wrote something!") 

if __name__=="__main__":    
    class_a = A()
    class_b = B()

    class_a.print_a()
    class_b.print_b()
```

I would like the output to be something like:

```
>> A says: a
>> B says: Warning! A wrote something!
>> B says: b
>> A says: Warning! B wrote something!
```

In other words: I have theese two classes (A and B). I would like to call a method of class A whenever another method of class B is called. Also, I would like to call a method of class B whenever another method of class A is called, assuming this would not cause an infinite loop (as in the example above).

In this case I would like to call 
    print_warning_a()
when
    print_b()
of class B fires, and also I would like to call 
    print_warning_b()
when
    print_a()
of class A fires.

How can I modify the code to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: If I get it correctly, you are trying to implement an event system, you could take a look there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092531/event-system-in-python

Comment: It looks like you don't totally get the difference between classes and instances...

Comment: It looks like you don't totally get the difference between someone who knows the differece between classes and istances and one who doesn't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to connect A and B somehow. An event system is an alternative, but if it's just a learning exercise we can do something simpler. For example, by saving references to the other class in each other, like this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = "a"
    def set_other(self, other):
        self.other = other
    def print_a(self):
        print("A says:", self.a)
        self.other.print_warning()
    def print_warning(self):
        print("A says:", "Warning! B wrote something!")

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = "b"
    def set_other(self, other):
        self.other = other
    def print_b(self):
        print("B says:", self.b)
        self.other.print_warning()
    def print_warning(self):
        print("B says:", "Warning! A wrote something!")

if __name__=="__main__":
    class_a = A()
    class_b = B()
    class_a.set_other(class_b)
    class_b.set_other(class_a)
    class_a.print_a()
    class_b.print_b()
```

I had to set the references *after* creating the instances, because we have a circular dependency. Also notice the correct way to declare attributes inside a class: `self.a = "a"`, inside the `__init__()` method. It works as expected:

```
A says: a
B says: Warning! A wrote something!
B says: b
A says: Warning! B wrote something!
```

Notice that the calls to the `other` reference are encapsulated inside methods, you're not supposed to expose calls like `other.other.other` to the outside world. In the end, there MUST be someplace where you have references to the `other` class (or references to *both* classes), it's unavoidable.

Comment: I din't post it, but this is quite similar to the solution I had in mind. The problem is that I don't really like to store one instance of a class inside another (and viceversa) because you could write: class_a.other.other.other.other.other ... .other.other and you can loose control on your actual reference...

Comment: That's why calls to the "other" are encapsulated inside methods, you're not supposed to expose calls like other.other.other to the outside world. Bottomline, there MUST be someplace where you have references to the other class (or both classes), it's unavoidable.

Comment: Please, Oscar, add this your last comment in your answer (I found it more clarifying the the actual answer ^^), in this way I think I can accept it. Thank you again for your time!

Comment: @Gigino I just did, thanks for your question and feedback :)