# Handling AdvancedSearchComplete event in Python

Tags: python, outlook

So I'm writing a program in Python that will traverse an Excel spreadsheet, get a PO number from it, and search our orders email account for that PO number. The problem is, when I print the number of results returned by the AdvancedSearch() method, it's usually zero (but not always - it's inconsistent).

I researched the problem a little and it looks like I need to handle the results using the AdvancedSearchComplete event. (I'm assuming the search usually doesn't find results before I try to print them in my code and that's why it's inconsistent.) I've tried to set up my code similarly to the code in this page: https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/, but it looks like the AdvancedSearchComplete event is handled automatically by the event handler in C# and VB.NET but not in Python. How can I handle this event in Python?

```py
import win32com
import win32com.client

outlook  = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
namespace = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
folders = namespace.Folders("orders@company.com")

def advanced_search(po, folders, outlook):
    scope = "'" + folders.Folders("Inbox").FolderPath + "','" + folders.Folders("Sent Items").FolderPath + "'"
    filter = "urn:schemas:httpmail:textdescription LIKE '%" + po + "%' OR urn:schemas:mailheader:subject LIKE '%" + po + "%'"
    search_subfolders = True
    tag = "This is a search"

    search = outlook.AdvancedSearch(scope, filter, search_subfolders, tag)

    print(search.Results.Count)

def Application_AdvancedSearchComplete(search):
    print("Advanced search completed")
```

EDIT: One suggestion I found was that the AdvancedSearchComplete event won't trigger if any code is being run after AdvancedSearch() is called. I tried removing the print statement in advanced_search() but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to the [AdvancedSearchComplete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.advancedsearchcomplete) of the Application class (which is `outlook` in your code). Simply pasting the event handler will not be working out of the box.

Comment: How would I do that? Every solution I've looked at responds to an event using a class (I think), but I just want to run a function when the event has occurred.

Comment: Sorry, but I am far away from Python. You may take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092531/event-system-in-python