# generator yielding upon object instantiation

Tags: python, iteration

I'm working on a big python project where user input is required during runtime. The requirement for input is encapsuled in a class `Decision` holding some meta information. Currently the decisions are handled in their own `__init__` (see below). These decisions are widely distributed over the code.

What I want to achive, is to turn the `work()` function into a generator which yields the decisions and they can be handled on top level (see comments).

In the example below I could easily yield the decisions from `somewhere_deep_in_code` to `work` and upwards, but this is not possible in the actual code. I although could process everything inside `work` in an other thread and wait for occuring decisions. But there is nothing actual async here and it seems wrong to do so. Maybe events or coroutines could do the trick, but I have no idea how. Due tue the fact this is a very special problem I did not find anything helpful in the comment sources. Therefore I would apriciate any help or ideas.

```
def handle_decision(decision):
    decision.value = 42

class Decision:
    def __init__(self, questions):
        self.questions = questions
        self.value = None
        handle_decision(self)  # this should go to top level

def somewhere_deep_in_code():
    decision = Decision("item1")
    # do sth with decision.value
    print(decision.value)
    somewhere_even_deeper_in_code()

def somewhere_even_deeper_in_code():
    decision = Decision("item2")
    # do sth with decision.value
    print(decision.value)

def work():
    somewhere_deep_in_code()

def main():
    # current implementation
    work()
    
    # how it should be
    for decision in work():
        handle_decision(decision)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you request a decision do you want to wait for one or rather proceed with other tasks? This article lists quite recent list of event systems available in Python: [Event system in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092531/event-system-in-python). GUI frameworks like Kivy are handling user interactions like events. Perhaps you can look at one for inspiration?

Comment: the decision.value needs to be set properly before continuing. As I said: nothing async here. I've read the linked question before. I just dont know how to use events to do what i want (or if its even possible).
And thanks for the Kivy hint! We already have a GUI but it looks like a great alternative.